# any(df.isna()) returns true when no NaNs are present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I create a DataFrame of floats and execute `any(df.isna())` it always returns True, regardless of the content of the array.  I would expect this to give the same result as `df.isna().any().any()`. What is it that I'm missing?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
print(f'Pandas version {pd.__version__}')
print(f'Numpy version {np.__version__}')
print(f'Python version: {sys.version}')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5, 3)))
print(f'The DataFrame:\n{df}')
print(f'Result of any(df.isna()): {any(df.isna())}')
print(f'Result of df.isna().any().any(): {df.isna().any().any()}')
```

Outputs:

```
Pandas version 1.1.4
Numpy version 1.19.4
Python version: 3.7.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov 27 2020, 18:48:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
The DataFrame:
          0         1         2
0  0.972085  0.418991  0.736300
1  0.603018  0.280435  0.981732
2  0.376201  0.343994  0.026125
3  0.002652  0.683785  0.729332
4  0.759530  0.792976  0.436991
Result of any(df.isna()): True
Result of df.isna().any().any(): False
```

Comment: I believe the reason is that any() function does not expect a df, you could use a list, tuple or dict. For example try to stack the elements of the df and turn them to ist. Then you'll get any(df.isna().stack().tolist())  a False .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `any` and `DataFrame` objects

The reason you're getting this output is that `any` returns `True` if any element of an iterable is evaluated as `True` otherwise `False`, and a `DataFrame` treated as an iterable will provide its column names. Any non-empty `str` evaluates as `True` and any non-zero `int` will evaluate as `True` - as in your given example - therefore `any` is acting as would be expected.

To get the expected output (`True` if any element of an iterable is evaluated as `True` otherwise `False`) based on the values contained within `df` you could use either of the following examples.

```py
df.isna().values.any() # Example 1
any(df.isna().values.flatten()) # Example 2
```

The use of `isdf.isna().values` returns a `numpy.ndarray` containing the values  of `df.na()` which are then used in one of two distinct `any` functions.

### First example explanation

The first example given uses [`numpy.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html)  instead of the [built-in `any` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). `numpy.any` evaluates all elements of all dimensions of a given `ndarray` if the `axis` kwarg is `None` (default).

### Second example explanation

The reason why [`numpy.ndarray.flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) is used in the second example is that `df.values` will return a multi-dimensional `ndarray` and as `any(args)` performs element-wise checks on the iterable passed, you will get the following error thrown at runtime.

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

`flatten` does exactly what it sounds like - maps values of a multi-dimensional `ndarray` to a single-dimensional one - which can be appropriately iterated across and evaluated using `any(your_flat_array)`.

I felt it pertinent to explain the difference between these two approaches here, though why you would decide to choose the second one would be a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `df.isna()` is a dataframe. And when you iterate a data frame, you are actually iterate over the column names:

```
for x in df.isna():
    print(x)
```

On the other hand the Python `any` function is something like this:

```
def anyPython(iterable):

    for x in iterable:
        if bool(x): return True

    return False
```

And what happens when you do `bool('some string')`?